# What is the meaning of the value property in a generated scikit learn decision tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am following the excellent talk on [Pandas and Scikit learn given by Skipper Seabold](http://pyvideo.org/depy-2015/classification-using-pandas-and-scikit-learn.html).

I am utilizing his [cleaned data set](https://github.com/jseabold/depy) that originates from [UCI adult names](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.names).

Upon running this code and generating the tree image via graphviz, we can observe there are value data on each node in the tree.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz

dta = pd.read_csv("data/adult.data.cleaned.csv")

for col in dta:
    if not dta[col].dtype.kind == "O":
        continue
    if dta[col].str.contains("\?").any():
        dta.ix[dta[col].str.contains("\?"), col] = "Other"
        test.ix[test[col].str.contains("\?"), col] = "Other"

dta.income.replace({"<=50K": 0, ">50K": 1}, inplace=True)
test.income.replace({"<=50K": 0, ">50K": 1}, inplace=True)

y = dta.pop("income")
y_test = test.pop("income")

X_train = pd.get_dummies(dta)
X_test = pd.get_dummies(test)

X_test[X_train.columns.difference(X_test.columns)[0]] = 0

dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=0, max_depth=6)
dtree.fit(X_train, y)
export_graphviz(dtree, feature_names=X_train.columns)
```

**What do the value properties represent?**
EDIT: Meaning in every node there is a `value=[x, y]` property

[image: Final decision tree]

Comment: what do you mean by 'what do these properties represent?'? that's the decision tree that fits your train data.

Comment: sry, the value part got lost somewhere in the question, please see the *edit*

Comment: value is the split of the samples at each node. so at the root node, 32561 samples are divided into two child nodes of 24720 and 7841 samples each.

Comment: I thought the same, but following the left-most nodes, the values on the 2nd non-root node (16425, 849) have a higher sum than the "left" value of the 1st non-root node (16436)

Comment: ok, my bad, they sum to the nodes "samples" property, now I understand. Thank you

Comment: cool. added a reference to the answer. accept if found useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value is how the samples to test for information gain are split up. So at the root node, 32561 samples are divided into 24720 and 7841 samples each.

Nice explanation from S. Raschka [here](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/decisiontree-error-vs-entropy.html)